# I have problem publishing my Android App on Google Play Store

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

I'm trying to upload my Android app on Google Play Store as (.aab) file, but I keep getting this error:

> Your App Bundle contains the following configurations where the
> initial install would exceed the maximum size of 150 MB: x86 +
> MDPI,armeabi-v7a + LDPI,armeabi-v7a + HDPI,armeabi-v7a +
> XHDPI,armeabi-v7a + XXHDPI,x86 + LDPI,x86 + XHDPI,armeabi-v7a +
> TVDPI,x86 + XXXHDPI,x86 + HDPI,x86 + TVDPI,armeabi-v7a + XXXHDPI,x86 +
> XXHDPI,armeabi-v7a + MDPI"

*Please note that my app has an embedded Unity Scene as (.aar) file*

Comment: What is the size of the .aab file ?
Google only allows 100MB per  .apk and .aab files

Comment: The size of .aab file is 180 mb

Comment: Reduce this size and replace the data in the .aar file , [link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) Here you will find some help

Comment: I reduced the size, and when I create an .aab file from Unity, It will upload without any problems, but when I embed the Unity in Native Android and create the .aab file from Android Studio I get that error.

Comment: Can you re-edit your question and add the new problems?